# Random errors causing Autosys Job Failure

Tags: r, unzip, autosys

I have an autosys running daily that basically fetches data from ftp server, then processes it and saves it to a shared drive and a database. The process uses an unzip method

```r
curl_download(url=ftp_url,destfile=zip_filename, mode="wb",handle=h)
file_list <- unzip(zip_filename,list=T)$Name
unzip(zip_filename,files=file_list,exdir=dir)
unlink(zip_filename)
```

Where `ftp_url` is an ftp site and `zip_filename` is a shared drive file.

I am receiving random errors in the process, most of the times at the unzip part, some of them being 'permission denied',  'file does not exist' (as the unzip happens successfully but file is not extracted at the location).

These errors come up randomly at any day, occur for a few days and then stop showing up.

Does anyone know the reasons behind these errors

I tried re running the code when it failed, but that didn't work

Comment: (1) You should probably include some exception-handling so that if either call to `unzip(.)` fails, you do not try the remaining expressions. (2) Some shared drives have a lag associated with them, where you think you create a file but it may not instantaneously be seen by all. Granted, in my experience, the process that created the file should _always_ see the file immediately, so I don't think that's it, but it would be interesting to know if the same `zip_filename` (without re-downloading) produces a different set of errors if you pause and try parts again.

Comment: (3) You don't share, but I suggest that your `zip_filename` should always be local, not on a shared drive (even if that shared drive is dropbox, onedrive, nextcloud, or the like). Do I know this would be a problem for you? No, but I know that this is often a problem for other things (like trying to build an R package on a shared drive ... often fails with perplexing errors).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this will work, but I think the "shared drive" provides the possibility for problem. (This can be a real network drive, or a virtual one like dropbox, onedrive, nextcloud, owncloud, etc.)

Try to use a completely-local path for both the download and unzipping portions, and then when done copy the resulting files to the shared drive. (I am assuming that `tempdir()` (under which `tempfile`-created files are placed) is on a local drive, not a shared drive.)

```r
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip") # used for the download
td <- tempfile()                 # used for extraction
dir.create(td)

curl_download(url = ftp_url, destfile = tf, mode = "wb", handle = h)
file_list <- unzip(tf, list = TRUE)$Name
unzip(tf, files = file_list, exdir = td)
# assuming `dir` is a target directory
file.copy(file.path(td, file_list), dir)

# cleanup
unlink(tf)
unlink(td, recursive = TRUE)
```

If your zip file contains subdirs, you might need to instead use

```r
file.copy(list.files(td, full.names = TRUE), dir, recursive = TRUE)
```

where the new call to `list.files` only returns the files and directories on the top-level within `td`, and the `recursive=TRUE` ensures that files within subdirs are copied as well.